# How to get separate serial numbers for different values in excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have these values in column A:

A1:a
A2:b
A3:a
A4:a
A5:b

I want to get serial numbers for all 'a' s in column B and serial numbers for all 'b' s in column C.

Please help me.

Comment: what do you mean by serial numbers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could think along the lines of a simple `COUNTIF` nested in an `IF`, like so:

[image]

Formula in `B1`:

```
=IF(A1="a",A1&"-"&COUNTIF($A$1:A1,A1),"")
```

Formula in `C1`:

```
=IF(A1="b",A1&"-"&COUNTIF($A$1:A1,A1),"")
```

Drag both down...

Obviously you have provided very little detail in your question, so change the outcome according to what you looking for (e.g. just the count on itself?)

Answer (score 0):

I too am a beginner in VBA but I could come up with a very straightforward and simple answer. Hope this is what you are trying to achieve:

```
Sub CopyPaste()

Dim i As Integer
LRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 1 To LRow

If Cells(i, 1) = "a" Then
Cells(i, 2) = i

ElseIf Cells(i, 1) = "b" Then
Cells(i, 3) = i
End If

Next i
End Sub
```